# Is there an option to wget to force it to write the response even when it's erroneous?

Tags: bash, soap, wget

I have written a Bash SOAP library that uses wget as the interface to HTTP servers.  It's intentional to avoid curl, since that is not available or not installed by default on systems where this library is used.

The basis of the library is the query the WSDL, determine the parameters and allow functions / methods to be invoked from the command line, through a simple wrapper to setup the SOAP urls:

```
$ ./mysoap.sh MyMethod sKey=1234 bAnotherParameter=False sAnotherParam="Hello"
```

However, when wget receives a 500 response, it doesn't write the response body to the output document defined by `-O`.  The response contains the SOAP errors that the server generated, which is useful to the client.  Is there a way to force wget to write the response to the output document, regardless of the state?  The documentation seems to be unclear about the function of `-O` in the event of an error, so to me, it's not working as intended.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the option:

Parameter: --content-on-error, available from wget 1.14:

https://superuser.com/a/648466

Comment: This will be why I can't see it in the doc then `GNU Wget 1.12 built on linux-gnu`. Thanks.

Comment: Have done.  SO is a bit sensitive to accepting answers within a certain time constraint.